# Intellij IDEA - Cascade or arrange project windows

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way in Intellij to arrange your windows?
We have multiple projects open at once and it would be nice to be able to be able to get Intellij to arrange them, cascaded from the top left of the screen.

I have hunted around for a built-in feature and/or a plugin, but found nothing.

Comment: Cascading windows of an app is normally an OS window management feature, not an app feature (even though it can be implemented inside an app). There is no built-in feature for this in IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm not aware of any plugin to do that.

Comment: @yole Thanks for that. I am on MacOS. I have a windows machine also which I will try

Comment: For Mac OS, you can try this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1042966/cascade-all-open-app-windows

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, the answer (on Mac OS) is: use Hammerspoon
Check out the link above or I can post my solution